# Wavelenth vs Absorbance plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a number of wavelengths and their corresponding absorbances.

First I entered the x and y values

```
x = [400 425 450 475 500 505 510 525];
y = [.24 .382 .486 .574 .608 .608 .602 .508];
```

To plot the points

> > plot(x, y, 'o')

Then I want to fit the data.
I'm not sure what degree of polynomial to choose, but since it's a plot of Wavelength vs Absorbtion, wont there already be a mathematical formula? Like how you know a plot of Kinetic energy vs Velocity will be degree 2 because KE = 1/2mv^2?

Comment: Yep scatter or plot would be fine. Look at hold on as well and polyfit/polyval to fit.

Comment: Don't hesitate to try something and ask if you're stuck anywhere! You might give some sample data as well :)

Comment: @Benoit_11 Could you look at my answer below please? I'm not sure what degree of polynomial to use.

Comment: Mhh it depends on your y values; can you provide them? You can also edit your question with this information. Thanks!

Comment: x values
400
425
450
475
500
505
510
525

Comment: y values
0.2400
0.3820
0.4860
0.5740
0.6080
0.6080
0.6020
0.5080

Comment: Alright I just posted an answer see if it works for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so here is a solution that works fine with your data, using polyfit and polyval to evaluate a polynomial that passes through your data points.

In the doc for polyfit ([here)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html#outputarg_S), it states that

> In general, for n points, you can fit a polynomial of degree n-1 to
>   exactly pass through the points.

Since you have 8 data points, we can try using a polynomial of degree 7 and see what it givesL

```
clear
clc

x = [400 425 450 475 500 505 510 525];
y = [.24 .382 .486 .574 .608 .608 .602 .508];

%// Get polynomial coefficients to fit the data
p = polyfit(x,y,7)

%// Create polynomial to plot
fFit = polyval(p,x);

plot(x,y,'o')
hold on
plot(x,fFit,'r--')
hold off

axis([400 525 0 .7]);

legend({'Data points' 'Fitted curve'},'Location','NorthWest')
```

gives this:

[image]

So it does look to work very well! If we look at the coefficients given by polyfit:

```
p =

   1.0e+05 *

  Columns 1 through 6

    0.0000   -0.0000    0.0000   -0.0000    0.0000   -0.0003

  Columns 7 through 8

    0.0401   -2.7206
```

Maybe the degree 7 was a bit overkill since the first 5 coefficients are 0 ( or about 0), but anyhow it fits very well!

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question

Comment: Fitting a 7th order polynomial to just 8 points will give very small residuals at the fitted point, but the curve might oscillate wildly everywhere else. But since you evaluate `fFit` only at the original `x`, you get almost the same points back, you could as well have done `plot(x,y,'o-')`. A better way to check the fit is `xfit=linspace(x(1),x(end),1000); yfit=polyval(p,xfit); plot(x,y,'o',xfit,yfit,'-r')`. Doesn't look too bad in this case, but doing high order fits is generally a bad idea. You might want to do spline-interpolation instead, if all you want is a smooth curve.

Comment: See the last graph about **overfitting** on [this page](http://www.libresoft.es/node/323) for what I mean.